# Migrate jetpack compose from 1.0.5 to 1.1.1 : Card issue

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I'm facing a weird issue with the latest stable version of Jetpack compose. When I was using version 1.0.5 everything was fine with `LazyColumn`

I'm migrating an app from Jetpack compose version `1.0.5` to `1.1.1`

but when I run the app, it shows some vertical gap between the `LazyColumn` items
[image]

When I checked, the `contentPadding` it still `0.dp` on the `LazyDsl.kt`

```
contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(0.dp)
```

I also haven't used any `verticalArrangement`

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending lots of hours, I found that the padding was generated by `onClick` on `JetpackCompose` `Card`. I fixed it using `Modifier.clickable{}` as below:

**Before**

```
    Card(
         elevation = paddingZero,
         onClick = { 
         // listener here
         }
    )
```

**After**

```
    Card(
        elevation = paddingZero,
        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
            // listener here
        }
    )
```

This fixed my issue. I hope this can be helpful to someone who is having same issue.